# Получить названия классов(css) из файла js

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Требуется написать регулярное выражение, которое бы возвращало классы. Пример приведен ниже:

На вход:

```
const data_div = one('.cl_1');
const edit = one('  .cl_2 .cl_edit_3 .cl_4  ');
const t_txt = one('             .1class5     ');
const textarea = one('#cl_edit6');
const ditdiv = one(".cl_7")
const app_div = one('.cl_8')[0];
```

На выходе
cl_1, cl_2, cl_edit_3, cl_4, 1class5, cl_edit6, cl_7, cl_8

Пробовал разные регулярные выражения:

1. /(?=[',"])((.*?)(?=\w)\w*\s*|^$)(?=[',"]) /gmi
2. /(?:[',"])((.*[^.])(?:[',"]))/gmi

И подобные. Не могу разобраться как поймать эти классы
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: `cl_edit6` — это `id`

Answer (score 0):

Вы не указали на каком языке, поэтому даю решение на JavaScript:

```js
const string = `
  const data_div = one('.cl_1');
  const edit = one('  .cl_2 .cl_edit_3 .cl_4  ');
  const t_txt = one('             .1class5     ');
  const textarea = one('#cl_edit6');
  const ditdiv = one(".cl_7")
  const app_div = one('.cl_8')[0];
`;

alert(
  string.match(/\.[^ '"]*/gi)
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g2Ljhanp